# Unable to create orainventory error in 12c

Tags: oracle

Installing the SAP NETWEAVER 7.5 in linux, during ORACLE installation, set the env varibale, DB_SID variable, after that gatting the error "unable to create the directory orainventory"

Please give me some points for solution for the same and What is the concept of orainventory.

Regards
Deepak

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: _"What is the concept of orainventory"_  The ora inventory is a directory (with subdirectories and files) that tracks what oracle products have been installed, and where.  It is critical to the installation, running, and maintenance of oracle databases, clients, etc.  Most likely you are not logged on to the OS with credentials needed to create it.  I'd suggest you go back and read the _offical_ Installation Guide - in detail.

Comment: Dear, When i am installing the NETWEAVER 7.5 and ORACLE 12C. in linux, in sapinst stop the installation and asking normally set the display env in oracle and proceed further, i have set the env and run the ./RUNINSTALLER after that it is showing the error "unable to create orainventory" issue. How i can create in linux and using which user?

Comment: And what are you setting the DISPLAY environment variable TO?  Runinstaller launches a GUI app, so needs a graphic display handler.  When I'm working with Linux, from my PC workstation, I start a graphic server called Exceed (look it up).  Then I connect to the linux machine using the ssh client 'PuTTY' (look it up) configured with x-11 port forwarding.  With that, I don't need to set DISPLAY.  Alternative to PuTTy, you can use a standard SSH client with the -X command line switch.

Comment: Hi The issue has been resolved. When installing the oracle during SAP in Linux environment., i set the env from orasid user, but the sapinst recommanded to logged on via oracle user then move forward. I fixed the issue login via oracle user and set the display env and move forward. Thanks for your support.